# Конфиденциальность в Tesseract OCR

Tags: безопасность, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Всем привет.Так как Tesseract OCR является OpenSource проектом, возник вопрос безопасности/конфиденциальности. Могут ли документы, которые я отправляю в Tesseract OCR попасть в открытый доступ в интернет? Используют ли наши отправленные изображения для дообучения нейросети Tesseract OCR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не могут. Данные не передаются по сети, все распознается у вас на локальном компьютере.